# php wrap every 3 elements in a tr for table

Tags: javascript, php, logic

In one of my table I want to have above us output but its little chnaged, Any help will be appreciated.

so...

```
<tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
```

becomes...

```
<tr class="new"> 
    <td></td> 
    <td></td> 
    <td></td> 
</tr> 
<tr class="new"> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are expecting? I am not getting your question.

Comment: every 3 td add tr with class with dynemic recordes in while loop

Answer (score 1):

If you have your html in string form you can perform some regex and loops on the string and get the desired outcome in array from, i'm not sure if this is what you're looking for..

```js
var result = html.match(/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/g).reduce(
 function(new_array,x,i,arr) {
  if(i % 3 == 0){
  new_array.push('<tr class="new">' + arr[i] + (arr[i+1] || '') + (arr[i+2] || '') + '</tr>');
  return obj;
               }
 }
,[])
```

Comment: Thanks for replay i want answer in php not in js

Comment: @JaydeepGondaliya could you please mention that in you question. And remove you javascript tag from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set counter for this, example :

```
        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($table_data as $single_table_date){

            if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '<tr>';
            }

            echo '<td>';
            echo $single_table_date;
            echo '</td>';

            $counter++;
        }
```